# Retrieve data from JSON object

Tags: json, postgresql

Have problem is selecting local_desc based on the langtype which is passed thru a procedure .

Sample table and data for your reference

```
create table test (local_id numeric, local_name json);

insert into test values (1, '{"language": [{"langtype": "EN", "Lang_desc": "English Smithline group"},{"langtype": "TH", "Lang_desc": "Thai Smithline group"}, {"langtype" :"AR", "Lang_desc":"Arabic Smithline group"}]}')

select local_id,local_name from test -- works fine

select local_id,local_name->'language' as lang from test    --- works fine

select local_id,local_name->'language'->>'Lang_desc' as lang from test where local_name->'language'->>'langtype'='EN' ---This query does not retrieve any data.. I want to get lang_desc based on the language parameter..
```

i am new to JSON and postgres. Pl help.

Answer (score 2):

`local_name->'language'` points to a json array. You should unpack the array using `json_array_elements()`:

```
select local_id, elem
from test, json_array_elements(local_name->'language') elem;

 local_id |                            elem                            
----------+------------------------------------------------------------
        1 | {"langtype": "EN", "Lang_desc": "English Smithline group"}
        1 | {"langtype": "TH", "Lang_desc": "Thai Smithline group"}
        1 | {"langtype" :"AR", "Lang_desc":"Arabic Smithline group"}
(3 rows)
```

Use the above query to select filtered data:

```
select local_id, elem->>'Lang_desc' lang_desc
from (
    select local_id, elem
    from test, json_array_elements(local_name->'language') elem
    ) sub
where elem->>'langtype' = 'EN';

 local_id |        lang_desc        
----------+-------------------------
        1 | English Smithline group
(1 row)
```